# getSupportActionBar setSubtitle only shows after activity recreation

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a generic

`MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

I don't override the toolbar with a custom xml defined toolbar, just use the generated one Android provides.

I can set the title via your normal

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("foo");`

but setting the subtitle via

`getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("bar");`

doesn't set it. It remains blank. I'm doing this `onCreate()`

(I feel I've done this many times before with no fail)

Although I've noticed if I visit another activity, then return, the subtitle would then show... not on orientation change, not on `recreate()` but only when I'm returning from an activity.

I'm experiencing this on 5.0 and 7.0

For the time being I'll likely define my own `Toolbar` and move forward since that seems where most people have solutions for this same problem.

Relevant code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_replenishment_list);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    MyApplication.getInstance().getComponent().inject(this);

    setupUI();
}

private void setupUI() {
    setupActionBar();
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        //TODO: not working unless activity is recreated...
        // explore custom xml defined toolbar
        //actionBar.setTitle("different title than what is defined in manifest"); <-- this does work, but not this
actionBar.setSubtitle(UserUtil.getFormattedFirstNameLastName(userService.getUserFromJWT(), this));


    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put your `getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("bar");` code?

Comment: @UmarZaii `onCreate()`

Comment: Can you include your code in the post? The activity code.

Comment: @UmarZaii updated

Comment: I have posted an answer please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I have put the below code in my `onCreate()` method.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar==null) {
    System.out.println("TEST NULL");
} else {
    System.out.println("TEST NOT NULL");
}
```

The result is `null`. When I add the toolbar first it works fine.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setSubtitle("TESTING");
```

Your `getSupportActionBar` or `getActionBar` will return `null` if you didn't set toolbar to it. You need to set the toolbar to your action bar before using `getSupportActionBar` or `getActionBar`.

Comment: Actually, `getSupportActionBar` doesn't return null (because we're using the generated one provided by Android) when it hits that code block. Adding the toolbar manually isn't the solution I was looking for (considering I'm doing that now as an alternative). I appreciate your effort